# Google maps issue using App Inventor

Tags: android, google-maps, app-inventor

Information here about the problem: The problem I am having with google app inventor is
bring text from a text box into google maps and having google maps try and find my location.

Screen shots:
http://s1164.photobucket.com/albums/q572/drebin8933/?start=all

-Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think... you can not do what you want to do currently.

Here is the Intents List http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

The Intent that runs Google Map uses a geo: URI in the DataUri

Look for Show a map for a location here http://appinventor4all.org/docs/learn/reference/other/activitystarter.html